# If $A, B$ forms a separation of $X$, does $A \cap Y$ and $B \cap Y$ forms a separation of Y when they are non-empty?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, solution-verification

Before I start, let me give three definitions.

> Definition (Separation): Let $X$ be a topological space. A **separation** of $X$ is a pair $U, V$ of disjoint non-empty open subsets of $X$ whose union is $X$. We will write a separation $U, V$ as $(U, V)$.
>
> Definition: A topological space $X$ is said to be connected if there does not exist a separation of $X$.
>
> Definition: A subset of a topological space $X$ is said to be connected if it is connected in the subspace topology.

My question revolves around this statement which I think is true.

> Claim: Let $X$ be a topological space; and let $Y$ be a subspace of $X$. Suppose $(A, B)$ is a separation of $X$. Then $(A \cap Y, B \cap Y)$ is a separation of $Y$ if and only if both $A \cap Y$ and $B \cap Y$ are non-empty.

This is a claim that sparked in my head when proving a theorem from Munkres' book, which is why I'm doubting its truth (as I'm very handicapped at topology). I think it may be true so I tried to prove it and the logic seems fine to me.

**Proof.** ($\implies$). This direction is trivial as suppose $(A \cap Y, B \cap Y)$ is a separation of $Y$, then by definition $A \cap Y$ and $B \cap Y$ are non-empty.

($\impliedby$).  Suppose $A\cap Y$ and $B \cap Y$ are non-empty. Since $(A, B)$ is a separation of $X$, $A$ and $B$ are open in $X$. Therefore, the two sets $A \cap Y$ and $B \cap Y$ are relatively open in $Y$. Moreover, observe that the two sets $A \cap Y$ and $B \cap Y$ are disjoint and their union is $Y$. Therefore, $(A \cap Y, B \cap Y)$ forms a separation of $Y$. $\rule{0.5em}{0.5em}$

My question is: Would there be any counterexamples to the claim as I could not think about one. Moreover, if there is a counterexample, would anyone be kind enough to reveal which part of the proof that is flawed.

If anyone has a thought on strengthening the conditions of this claim, I would also welcome that.

Comment: The claim is true and your proof is correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Would this more general claim still hold? Claim: ``$X$ topological space and $Y$ subspace of $X$; and suppose $(A, B)$ is a separation of $X$. Then $Y$ is not connected if and only if $A \cap Y$ and $B \cap Y$ are both non-empty.'' The forward direction seems false to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is true; note indeed that $A \cap Y$ and $B \cap Y$ are relatively open in $Y$, still disjoint, and if $A \cup B $ covered $X$, their intersections with $Y$ cover $Y$; so the only "concern", or possible problem, with being a separation is that both parts should be non-empty. So your proof is correct, and if both parts are non-empty, we get a separation of the subspace.

A consequence of this observation is that if $X$ disconnected and $(U,V)$ is a disconnection, then for every connected subspace $Y$ of $X$, either $Y \subseteq U$ or $Y \subseteq V$. This is often used in proofs involving connectedness.

Comment: I see. How about if we consider the more general claim: $X$ topological space and $Y$ subspace of $X$; and suppose $(A, B)$ is a separation of $X$. Then $Y$ is not connected if and only if $A \cap Y$ and $B \cap Y$ are both non-empty? Would the forward direction still be true?

The reverse direction is clear by the original claim. But the forward direction is not so and I'm still trying to prove it.

Comment: @devianceee yes, that’s exactly the same claim.except that $Y$ can be disconnected and still miss one of $A$ or $B$. So the forward claim fails.

Comment: what do you mean by ''miss''?

Comment: @devianceee is disjoint from.

Comment: ahh you meant that it is possible that either $A \cap Y = \emptyset$ or $B \cap Y = \emptyset$ even though $Y$ is disconnected. So the forward direction is not true then.

Comment: okay I found a counterexample, by considering $X = (-1, 0) \cup (0, 1)$ endowed with the subspace topology and the subspace $Y = (0, 1/2) \cup (1/2, 1)$ of $X$. Thank you again!